# Are there any new/alternate Reincarnate Tables?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

3.5 has countless Splat books with numerous new races, yet I have been unable to find any new/alternate Reincarnate Tables.

Do any (preferably "official" 3.5) alternate tables exist to address the new races? Yes, technically a roll of 100=other but that's a very slim roll to get some non-core race.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No, there are *almost* no official alternative [*reincarnate*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/reincarnate.htm) charts

It's likely the expectation is that the DM adjusts the chart based on his campaign. That's because, if I remember correctly, when *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* was in the planning stages, one of the complaints fans of *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, 2nd Edition* had was the necessity of cross-referencing a brand new *2nd Edition* book with many other, sometimes out-of-print *2nd Edition* books. To mollify detractors, the *3rd Edition* design paradigm was to keep books as self-contained as possible, using references to other sources only when absolutely necessary. This continued into the *3.5* era, and explains, for example, why there're no comprehensive *D&D 3.5* random encounter tables and, for example, why monsters who would benefit greatly from the feats Martial Study (*ToB* 31-2), Travel Devotion (*CC* 62-3), or Shock Trooper (*CW* 112) don't have those feats and, instead, have feats like [Alertness](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#alertness) (*PH* 89).

### *Reincarnate* Variants

Published variants to the 4th-level Drd spell [*reincarnate*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/reincarnate.htm) [trans] (*PH* 270) include the following:

- Kieth Baker's Dragonshard's column ["Druids of Khorvaire, Part Two"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210920212854/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebds/20051024a) presents an **alternative reincarnation chart** for the [Eberron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberron) campaign setting.
- The 4th-level Drd spell ***last breath*** [trans] (*SpC* 130) reincarnates a target that's been dead 1 round or less, and that target suffers no level or Constitution loss.
- The 8th-level Drd spell ***cocoon*** [conj] (*SpC* 49-50) reincarnates the target, and that target suffers no level or Constitution loss. The spell's effect takes a week to kick in.
- The 8th-level Drd spell ***dire reincarnation*** [trans] ([*Dungeon* #100 Web Enhancement "The Lich-queen's Beloved"](https://paizo.com/dungeonissues/100/Dungeon100Enhancement.pdf)) reincarnates the target as a nonhumanoid *Monster Manual* creature. This spell has its own chart. *Note:* Link goes to free PDF.
- The 9th-level Drd spell ***true reincarnate*** [trans] (*MW* 96) reincarnates a target that's been dead a long time, and the target suffers no level or Constitution loss.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of, but if you're in the DM, it wouldn't be hard to make one that fit your needs using Internet References. Allow me to demonstrate;

### Reincarnation Chart

**Roll a d100**

- 01-85: Consult [This Post](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1281.msg10194#msg10194), and the following one, rolling a d126
  to determine which race*
- 86-90: Consult [This Post](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1281.msg10210#msg10210), rolling a d10 to determine which race
- 91-95: Consult [This Post](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=10508317&postcount=1), rolling a d48 and consulting the first list to determine which race
- 96-99: Consult [This Post](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showsinglepost.php?p=10508317&postcount=1), rolling a d18 and consulting the second list to determine which race
- 100: Reroll, but choose a random, funny, dramatically appropriate template to apply to the result

*Each block contains 10 races for easy counting

If the chart calls for a die you don't own, [the official WotC online dice roller](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/dice/dice.htm) can manage.

If you find that chart to be too broad, go ahead and narrow things down to only include things you want to see walking around in your game.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew alert: I created a custom Reincarnate table a few years back.

It looks like this:

```
d%     Incarnation
==================================================
<=5    Caster's race
6-10   Target's choice (other than old race)
11-40  Same as old race
41-50  Related race (GM's adjucation)
51-60  Decidedly unrelated race (GM's adjucation)
61-90  Roll randomly among races in the setting
91+    GM's choice
```

This is all subject to the constraint that the creature's LA and/or HD may not change (except as is normal for level loss).

Clearly, this (describing general results) is a very different approach from the one taken by the default Reincarnate table (explicitly determining races). The reason is that different groups use different races.

Any explicit table either has too few races, resulting in some of the group's races not being included, or too many, resulting in the table that includes races the group does not traditionally include.

The downside is that the spell now sometimes requires a lot more DM input. I think that's OK. Death and Reincarnation doesn't happen *that* often, and is usually a significant enough event to spend some time on thinking about how to resolve it anyway.

But the biggest advantage I see with this approach is that the spell no longer has to assume humanoids as the target. Animal companions everywhere, rejoice.